# Error Handling with ResponseStatusException class

Tags: java, spring, controller, frameworks

All of the controllers on my projects extend from one Base controller that uses the  `@ExceptionHandler` annotation. Seeing as what I'm currently using is a bit older than the new way to handle exceptions that spring introduced I'm trying to update my project by replacing my `ExceptionHandler` annotations with the most recent `ResponseStatusException` class.

Any tips on how to do that properly?